# Fill Model Class With query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hello I Have the Following Model

```
public class MainClass
{
    public List<SubClass1> First { get; set; }
    public List<SubClass2> Second { get; set; }
    public List<SubClass3> Third { get; set; }
}

public class SubClass1
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class SubClass2
{
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }            
}

public class SubClass3
{
    public string Prop4 { get; set; }
    public string Prop5 { get; set; }
}
```

I need to "fill" the MainClass with a linq query result, I'm trying to do it this way:

```
var resultado = from a in DataContext.Table1
                        join b in DataContext.Table2 on a.Id equals b.CId
                        select new MainClass
                        {
                           First = new SubClass1 ... list query result,

                           Second = new SubClass2 ... list query result,

                           Third = new SubClass3 ... list query result,                               
                        };
```

How can I "fill" the SubClasses in order to construct the MainClass.

Comment: is your current code throwing an error or something? What is wrong with what you're trying to do right now?

Comment: Can you show more of what you have tried and what results you are getting when you are trying to fill MainClass?

Comment: Hello yes my code is showing syntax errors, this code is just an example.

Comment: you'll have to show your query results.  It'll end up like `First = query.FirstModel.ToList()`

Comment: I'm doing this way example:

 First = new SubClass1
                                                           {
                                                               Name = a.Name,
                                                               Code = a.Code,
                                                               Category = a.Category
                                                           }

But I have this error "Can not implicitly convert type SubClass1 in System.Generic.List<SubClass1>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this

```
var resultado = from a in DataContext.Table1
                    join b in DataContext.Table2 on a.Id equals b.CId
                    select new MainClass
                    {
                       First = ( from i in db.Entity where somecondition).ToList<SubClass1>()
                       , Second = (from s in db.Entity2 where ).ToList<SubClass1>()

}
```

and so on..